# Filling form with JavaScript from Console

Tags: javascript, scripting, console, textarea

Suppose I've got a form in which I've got a text field that I need to add. Field is repeated 100 times.

```
...
<textarea class="typeInStupid" data-text-type="execution-notes" 
placeholder="Notes go here..." rows="6" id="123"></textarea>
...
...
<textarea class="typeInStupid" data-text-type="execution-notes" 
placeholder="Notes go here..." rows="6" id="124"></textarea>
...
```

Task: using browser Console and JavaScript to add the same chunk of text (f.e. "BlaBla") to all text fields so that:

```
...
<textarea class="typeInStupid" data-text-type="execution-notes" 
placeholder="Notes go here..." rows="6" id="123">BlaBla</textarea>
...
...
<textarea class="typeInStupid" data-text-type="execution-notes" 
placeholder="Notes go here..." rows="6" id="124">BlaBla</textarea>
...
```

Alternative efficient solutions - yes please. :) 
thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to find all the textarea fields and then iterate through each one and modify its value.

```
var textFields = document.querySelectorAll(".typeInStupid");
for (var i = 0; i < textFields.length; i++) {
    textFields[i].value = "BlaBla";
}
```

Please see [JSFiddle with DOM](http://jsfiddle.net/bruceyang/7sp27tv4/). You just need to copy the javascript code to browser console window and execute it.

Alternatively, if you use jquery,

```
$(".typeInStupid").each(function(){
    $(this).val("BlaBla");
});
```

as shown in [JSFiddle with JQuery](http://jsfiddle.net/bruceyang/7sp27tv4/1/)

Comment: You shouldn't use .getElementsByClassName because it does not have IE8 support. If you are going the straight JavaScript route then you should replace it with .querySelectorAll. This is supported in IE8. Alternatively using jQuery makes life so so much easier.

Comment: You could simply do this by var textFields = document.querySelectorAll(".typeInStupid"); that seems a little simpler. :)